# powershell dll method not found

Tags: powershell, methods, dll

I have a PowerShell script where I want to set a Value in some method.
I use a dll, and I now these methods exists in this dll file.

But for some reason, I still get a method not found exception.

I updated the dll and printed the filename, in my script, so I am sure that my script using the right dll.
I checked the dll and the method exist.

In the same file, I have another method that I use, en this works perfectly.

I thought maybe I had a writing error but didn't found one.

```bsh
$messagingDllPath = Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath 'dll/OneHIP.Messaging.dll' | Resolve-Path
Add-Type -Path $messagingDllPath # Add assembly

[OneHIP.Messaging.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsProvider]::SetValue("ClientId","idValue")

[OneHIP.Messaging.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsProvider]::SetValue("ClientSecret","secret")
```

```
<member name="M:OneHIP.Messaging.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsProvider.SetValue(System.String,System.String)">
            <inheritdoc/>
</member>
```

```
2019-09-23T08:18:30.3228501Z ##[error]ValidateBusConfiguration : System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Metho
d invocation failed because [OneHIP.Messaging.Configuration.ApplicationSettings
Provider] doesn't contain a method named 'SetValue'.
   at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(F
unctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(Inte
rpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.
Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.
Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
At \\eqx-prd-ohfs.appliarmony.net\MSG\OneHipConfigurationValidationTfsBuildTask
\ValidateOneHIPConfiguration.ps1:217 char:9
+         ValidateBusConfiguration
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorExcep 
   tion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorExceptio 
   n,ValidateBusConfiguration
```

Does somebody have an idea what the problem is here?

Comment: I think the function is called [SetPropertyValues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.settingsprovider.setpropertyvalues?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: In our code we sure have a methode called Set Value.
public string SetValue(string settingName, string value)
        {
            var oldValue = GetValue(settingName);
            _storedValues[settingName] = value;
            return oldValue;
        }

Comment: Is your method static?  You are using PowerShell's static method calling convention (i.e. using the `::` operator).  If it isn't, you'll need to create an instance of your type first (with `New-Object`), then call with the instance method syntax (i.e. with the `.` operator).  Check if the method is known to PowerShell by using `Get-Member`: `[TypeName] | Get-Member`.  Add the `-Static` switch to see the static methods.

Comment: Ah thanks, there is the problem, the method is not static.

Comment: Cool.  I added my comment as an answer so it's easier to find in future.  Feel free to accept it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the method is known to PowerShell by using `Get-Member`:

`$ObjectInstance | Get-Member`

Add the `-Static` switch to see the static methods:

`$ObjectInstance  | Get-Member -Static`

This latter option also works with types directly:

`[TypeName] | Get-Member -Static`

You are using PowerShell's static method calling convention (i.e. using the `::` operator). If it isn't static (which you've since confirmed), you'll need to create an instance of your type first (with `New-Object`), then call with the instance method syntax (i.e. with the `.` operator).

Answer (score 0):

The method was not Static.

By creating a new instance, I was able to call the SetValue method.

Thanks to @boxdog